# Laravel nested array validation message

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a nested array of json that I need to validate. I'm trying to give the custom validation messages for the fields in the array. I've look through the docs and some posts but I still cant figure this out. The rules that I specified is:

```
    return [
        'member_id'                 => 'required|exists:member,id',
        'payment_method'            => 'required',
        'items.*.products.*.id'       => 'required|exists:product,id',
        'items.*.products.*.quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'items.*.packages.*.id'       => 'required|exists:package,id',
        'items.*.packages.*.quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1'
    ];
```

In my messages function

```
   public function messages(){
        return [
            'custom' => [
                'items.*.products.*.id' => [
                    'required'  => 'Product ID is required.',
                    'exists' => 'Selected product invalid.',
                ],
            ],
        ];
   }
```

However my validation message is still:
`The selected items.0.products.0.id is invalid.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   public function messages(){
        return [
            'items.*.products.*.id.required' => 'your message here',
            'items.*.products.*.id.exists' => 'your message here',
            'items.*.products.*.id.exists' => 'your message here',
            'items.*.products.*.quantity.required' => 'your message here',
            'items.*.products.*.quantity.integer' => 'your message here',
            'items.*.products.*.quantity.min' => 'your message here',
            // etc... you get the idea
        ];
   }
```

> See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-error-messages 
>   Specifying A Custom Message For A Given Attribute

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using without `custom` key like this :

```
public function messages(){
    return [
         'items.*.products.*.id' => [
                'required'  => 'Product ID is required.',
                'exists'    => 'Selected product invalid.',
         ]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define just custom **attribute names** instead of a lot of custom messages!

```php
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'items.*.products.*.id' => 'product',
        'items.*.products.*.quantity' => 'product quantity',
        'items.*.packages.*.id' => 'package',
        'items.*.packages.*.quantity' => 'package quantity',
    ];
}
```

Your validation message would be: `The selected product is invalid.`

> See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#customizing-the-validation-attributes